# AH00526: Syntax error on line 6 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-ispconfig.vhost:

Tags: server, 20.04, apache2

I cannot start apache2 server so I run

`apache2ctl configtest`

I got the next results:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 6 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-ispconfig.vhost:
Listen requires 1 or 2 arguments.
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

Then, I took a look to that file:

`nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-ispconfig.vhost`

An this is what I have on the first 6 lines:

```
######################################################
# This virtual host contains the configuration
# for the ISPConfig controlpanel
######################################################

 Listen Admin password [admin]:
```

Any sugestion to make it work?

Ubuntu Server 20.04.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running? Generally the virtual host configuration files have a different file extension 

Comment: Hi @matigo, it is release 20.04. And I have instaled ISPConfig 3. Indeed, the issue pops up as I want to reach ISPConfig 3 via browser and then I realized that apache2 was not running.